# Asyncio и Aiogram. Ошибка при отправке сообщения event loop is closed

Tags: python, telegram-bot, flask, aiogram, asyncio

У меня есть telegram бот написанные на python с использованием библиотеки aiogram. Так же есть flask сервер. Мне нужно было сделать, чтобы бот отправлял сообщения после обработки маршрута flask`ом, я решил это сделать таким образом:

```
async def SendWorkerMessage():
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=XXXXXXX, text=f"Ваша регистрация прошла успешно!")
```

А в обработчике маршрута вызываю эту функцию:

```
asyncio.run(SendOrderToChat())
```

Но проблема в том, что бот 1 раз отправляет сообщение, а на второй и последующие разы я получаю:

> Event loop is closed

Объясните пожалуйста в чем причина и как ее можно исправить. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Причина в том, что asyncio.run нельзя запускать больше одного раза. Flask с версии 2.0 умеет работать с асинхронными вьюхами, используйте это

Comment: @andreymal Я попробовал использовать следующую конструкцию:
 `@app.route('/order', methods=['POST'])
async def result():
    try:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=311757564, text="Привет")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Ошибка ", err)
    return make_response("", 200)`
Но по прежнему получаю ошибку _Event loop is closed_

Comment: фласк также запускает луп на каждый запрос. тут наверное проблема в том что сам бот запущен без лупа.